# Symfony - test the sfDoctrineApplyPlugin mail functionality locally?

Tags: php, email, symfony1, localhost

Okay, so I finnaly enabled the plugin and almost got it to work - followed the instructions at http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineApplyPlugin.

I stumbled accross alot of problems while doing it:

**1)** in the schema, the user_id field has to be set as integer, and not integer***(4)*** as the author written - else you're gonna get a error 1005 from mysql, complaining about foreign key - this is because the field in sfGuardUser, the id, is set as integer and not integer(4).

**2)** Assuming you downloaded the full version of Zend, when installing it, the folder you need is the library/Zend one (not the whole ZendFramework, which I thought I needed). Here I had plenty of "unable to include" errors before i realized what's the problem.

**3)** After I fixed this, I got the error on this line - "$mailer->disconnect();", saying $mailer isnt declared. This line is inside a catch() clause, so I commented it - and now it seems to be working.

BUT! I beleive the reason I'm getting this error is because my project is driven localy. Because as soon as i commented the mentioned line, it worked and I got an error saying "An error took place during the email delivery process. Please try again later. "

So my question is: how can i test this plugin and the mail functionalities it offers locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I came accross this article http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html.

I managed to solve my problem by following the instructions and getting my ISP's SMTP address.

Takes way less time, so I recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a mail server of some form, and which one depends on your current setup.

If you're using SMTP to send mail (it should be obvious if you are, the class is Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp), the I've seen [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/64753/smtp-server-on-windows-7) on serverfault, and [apparently](http://dbaron.org/linux/sendmail) you can use sendmail on Linux. Personally, I use Dovecot and Postfix, but that is not for the faint of heart.

If you're not using SMTP, sendmail works well, but that is a *nix tool (yum and aptitude both let you install this easily). In Windows, I know of [Mercury](http://www.pmail.com/), but you'll have to look into configuring with your Apache instance and PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I downloaded smtp4dev but couldn't seem to configure it to work with PHP.